# Webpagetest.org - does repeat view display browser cache?

Tags: performance, cache, testing

In the documentation is written, to generate the repeat view webpagetest closes the browser and launches it again. Does it mean, the browser cache goes on restart empty and doesn't play any role on repeat view?

Comment: Closing a browser window does not clear the cache, so yes, repeat view will use the cache.

Comment: That depends.  My browser has a setting for clearing the browser cache when it is closed.

Comment: Fair point. But from the point of view of webpagetest, the purpose (IMO) of repeat view is to test browser caching of your resources. This is also pretty easy to verify by just running a test: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180313_PF_06a61bfa0f0e5f66044bc7ea21e69b4d/

Comment: @TimFountain exactly so was my thought. Is there a way to differ a browser and a server cache? I mean: to get to know, what is caching?

Comment: webpagetest is not going to be able to reliably determine the benefits of a server-side cache since a server-side cache might have been used on the "First View" (depends on how _you_ are managing server-side caching, and whether this is per-user or not.)

Comment: @MrWrite but you can test server-side caching by running the test before enabling and after.

Comment: @Evgeniy Web Page Test uses a browser to test your site, so all default browser rules apply.

Comment: @SimonHayter do you mean: run test only with `first view` and than with activated `repeat view`?

Comment: err? I mean they visit your site the first time and then the 2nd time they visit your site they do not download your resources such as JS/CSS/JPG etc unless you have disabled caching server-side e.g zero expires.